# How to access files from a directory in apache storm

Tags: apache-storm

How to access the files in a directory by a bolt of apache storm topology

in the topology class im passing object of AnnotationTest class

```
Config conf = new Config();
conf.put("gateObject", new AnnotationTest());
```

In a bolt class im accessing that object

```
  AnnotationTest at;
  @Override
  public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context) {

      at=(AnnotationTest)stormConf.get("gateObject");
    }
```

But the AnnotationTest class accessing lot of resources from the directory **sand**
the sand directory also included in the root of the jar file (storm-starter-0.9.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar)

the maven build script below

```
<resource>
     <directory>.</directory>
     <includes>
     <include>sand/**/*.*</include>
     </includes>
</resource>
```

but when accessing the a file from that sand directory in AnnotationTest class like below

```
application = (ConditionalSerialAnalyserController) PersistenceManager
                    .loadObjectFromUrl(new URL("file:///sand/application.xgapp"));
```

All the source codes, dependencies, resource directories included in that single jar file 
Im submitting the topology by running the topology class which also inside the same jar file by the following command

```
storm jar storm-starter-0.9.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar backtype.storm.testing.CopyTopology
```

the following Exception raising

```
6892 [main-EventThread] INFO  org.apache.storm.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: CONNECTED
6930 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Starting supervisor with id 60c35cb1-f020-4f6f-bc79-fcafe3fff844 at host ubuntu
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sand/application.xgapp (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager.isXmlApplicationFile(PersistenceManager.java:1013)
    at gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromUrl(PersistenceManager.java:857)
    at backtype.storm.testing.AnnotationTest.<init>(AnnotationTest.java:38)
    at backtype.storm.testing.CopyTopology.submitTopology(CopyTopology.java:30)
    at backtype.storm.testing.CopyTopology.main(CopyTopology.java:54)
```

So please show me a way to access the files from a directory (which available inside the jar file) in bolt class of the storm topology.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` exception. This indicates that the path of the file 'application.xgapp' that you are passing to the `java.net.URL` constructor, does not contain the file. From your question description, it seems that you have kept the file at the root of the jar. If this is true, you can't form a URI to a file within the jar this way - "file:///sand/application.xgapp".

Change

```
application = (ConditionalSerialAnalyserController) PersistenceManager
                    .loadObjectFromUrl(new URL("file:///sand/application.xgapp"));
```

to

```
application = (ConditionalSerialAnalyserController) PersistenceManager
                    .loadObjectFromUrl(new URL("file:/<jar-path>/<yourjar.jar>!/sand/application.xgapp"));
```

Alternately, you can move sand/application.xgapp outside the jar and use your current form of URI.